# Django-Rest-Framework serializer class meta

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

as I can use two in a meta model class, when I run it I get an error
How I can use the models? It is an example of Django Rest

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post,Miembros

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'titulo', 'contenido','fecha_evento','fecha_evento','banner_grande','lugar')

        model = Miembros
        fields = '__all__'
```

> TypeError at /api/posts/ The `fields` option must be a list or tuple.
>   Got str. Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/
>   Django Version:   1.8.3 Exception
>   Type: TypeError Exception Value:   The `fields` option must be a list
>   or tuple. Got str. Exception
>   Location: /home/root-master/restcosolg/cslg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py
>   in get_field_names, line 900 Python
>   Executable:   /home/root-master/restcosolg/cslg/bin/python Python
>   Version:  2.7.6

Comment: Did you try to add all of the field members for the Miembros as you did in the post model to see if that is the issue, or do you get the same error?

Answer (score 29):

I know this answer is several years after the question was asked, but I've run into this situation a couple of times. For some reason it's expecting a list instead of a single value.

So if you don't want to use the `__all__` value, but you only have 1 value in your model, you need to make sure there is a comma , in the fields section:

```
class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Lifesaver! yes that comma syntax is the issue for me

Answer (score 17):

**Update (5 May 2016):**

**`__all__` value for `fields` is [now supported](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) in `ModelSerializer`(Thanks [@wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) for pointing out).**

> You can also **set the `fields` attribute to the special value `'__all__'`**
>   to indicate that all fields in the model should be used.
>
> If you only want a subset of the default fields to be used in a model
>   serializer, you can do so using `fields` or `exclude` options, just as you
>   would with a `ModelForm`. It is **strongly recommended that you explicitly
>   set all fields that should be serialized using the `fields` attribute.**
>   This will make it less likely to result in unintentionally exposing
>   data when your models change.

<del>It seems you are trying to mix Django ModelForm [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) attribute with the DRF serializer [`fields`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) attribute.

In a DRF serializer, `__all__` is an invalid value for the `fields` attribute.</del>

**Secondly,** you can't specify multiple models in a `Meta` class.  You will need to use 2 separate serializers and attach them with each other.

For example you can do something like below:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post,Miembros


class MiembrosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    serializer for Miembros model
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Miembros 
        fields = '__all__' # all model fields will be included


class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    serializer for Post model
    """

    miembros = MiembrosSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'titulo', 'contenido','fecha_evento','fecha_evento','banner_grande','lugar')
```

Comment: It seems this answer is outdated.  [DRF supports the `'__all__'` djangoism](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) now.